# How to remove gaps between the tables and tr

Tags: html

```
    <table width="33%" border="0" border-spacing: 0px; cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><img src="01.png" width="619" height="143" " /></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="13" valign="top"><img 02.png" width="75" height="13" /></td>
      <td width="32%" valign="top"><img src="03.png" width="200" height="13" /></td>
      <td width="56%" colspan="2" valign="top"><04.png" width="344" height="13" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
  <td colspan="4" valign="top"><img 05.png" width="619" height="150" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="4" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="85%"><img src="06.png" width="474" height="28" /></td>
      <td width="11%"><img src="07.png" width="71" height="28" /></td>
      <td width="4%"><img src="08.png" width="74" height="28" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" valign="top"><img src="09.png" width="619" height="144" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="76%" height="32"><img src="10.png" width="474" height="32"/></td>
    <td width="12%"><img src="11.png" width="71" height="32"/></td>
    <td width="12%"><img src="12.png" width="74" height="32"/></td>
  </tr>
</table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" valign="top"><img src="13.png" width="619" height="140" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" valign="top"><table width="99%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
    <td width="76%"><img src="14.png" width="474" height="36"/></td>
    <td width="12%"><img src="15.png" width="71" height="36" /></td>
    <td width="12%"><img src="16.png" width="74" height="36"/></td>
  </tr>
</table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td height="109" colspan="4" rowspan="2" valign="top"><img 19.png" width="619" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have this code in my email template. When I compile it on my local page, it works fine, but when I send it though email, gaps are appearing in between the lines and tables. I tried this also

```
    <style>
table { border-spacing: 0px; }
</style>
```

But not worked. Anybody know about this issue?

Or how I should print it in php? so that it sends as an image in email. Because after receiving an email, when I forward it, then its shows me correct because it become an image. So I am thinking to make it as an image before shooting email in the script. But how can I print this html in php?

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but this line has an error `<table width="33%" border="0" border-spacing: 0px; cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">`. Border-spacing should be specified within a `style=""` attribute. Something like this: `<table width="33%" border="0" style="border-spacing: 0px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<table ... border-spacing: 0px; ...>
```

This isn't valid markup. `border-spacing` would be put within a `style` property:

```
<table ... style="border-spacing: 0px;" ...>
```

To remove the spacing, you'd simply add:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
</table>
```

Comment: @AbrarKiyani try cellpadding and cellspacing in table.

Comment: can anybody tell me how can I print it in php?

Comment: worked by placing style="display: block;" at the end of images